# Is there a way to check null or undefined in a series of object of objects in lodash

Tags: javascript, user-interface, ecmascript-6, lodash, ecmascript-5

Let's consider a scenario in the below example, where I want to check the value of the object `x.a.b` or `x.a.b.c`, but it is throwing an exception while trying to access the object at second level (`x.a.b`) 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'b' of undefined'.

Ultimately I want to access `x.a.b.c`, and how can I check if the value is not 'undefined' or 'null' using lodash?
Is there a way to check the object in a series of values?

```
var x = {}
!_.isUndefined(x); // true
!_.isUndefined(x.a); // false
!_.isUndefined(x.a.b); // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'b' of undefined
```

Answer (score 3):

Use lodash's `_.get()` to get the suspected path. It will return `undefined` or a default value, if the parts of the path don't exist.

**Note**: if you want to catch `null`, and `undefined` use `_.isNil()` instead of `_.isUndefined()`.

```js
var x = {}
console.log(!_.isUndefined(x)); // true
console.log(!_.isUndefined(_.get(x, 'a'))); // false
console.log(!_.isUndefined(_.get(x, 'a,b')));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

Another option is the optional chaining which as stage 4 ES proposal (not supported by browsers, but can be enabled with Babel):

```
var x = {}
console.log(!_.isUndefined(x)); // true
console.log(!_.isUndefined(x?.a)); // false
console.log(!_.isUndefined(x?.a?.b));
```

Comment: var x = {};
x.a = {};
x.a.b = 1;
_.get(x, 'a') // {}, which is correct, but
_.get(x, 'a, b') // undefined, it not returning correct value, as it should return 1

Comment: @SarveshMahajan - please explain.